# How does Entity Framework generate a GUID for a primary key value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When we run the ASP.NET application and register the user, Entity Framework automatically sets the unique id (PK) in AspNetUser table:

[image]

The same is true for other AspNetRoles, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles
except AspNetUserClaims which has identity enabled.

Can anybody explain how Entity framework create this unique Id? And if we want to create our own table with identity disabled in EF, how will we generate this kind of Id for primary key?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to use a GUID as primary key value? It has quite some drawbacks over the good old 32 or 64 bit integer. You also seem to confuse "identity" with "int". Setting "identity" means the database will generate the primary key value for new rows, regardless of the type (for supported types only though).

Comment: Entity framework does this.

Comment: I'm responding to your _"And if we want to create our own table [...] how will we generate this kind of Id?"_. Why would you want to use a GUID as the PK for your tables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The GUID is not generated by `Entity Framework` nor by `SQL`. It is handled by **Identity framework**. Just navigate to `IdentityModels.cs`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   // ...
}
```

This class is inherited from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser` and constructor for this class is defined as ([Source](https://github.com/mhowlett/AspNet.Identity.Providers/blob/8c6774c8957e4b9276310e150c6ff9c04f1341c6/AspNet.Identity.Providers.Common/IdentityUser.cs#L16))

```
public IdentityUser()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

So GUID is generated in the constructor. This is same for other Identity tables too.

Note: Id Field is `varchar (string)` in database.

Comment: This approach makes it so I can set the value without the database.  Which for my purpose is what I want, since I'm [serializing to xml file](https://youtu.be/ATrXdq0LGpQ)

Comment: this is true only for default key type IdentityUser<string>

Answer (score 32):

This unique Id is created by SQL Server on insert.

If you want to let SQL Server generate the value on insert, you have to use the following attributes in your model :

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Or if you want to manage the Id by yourself, just generate it :

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 2):

EF isn't generating that value. That's a GUID (`uniqueidentifier` in T-SQL) value which is auto-generated by SQL Server when a new row is INSERTed,.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Identity` in ASP .NET,id are automatically generated in db (uniqueidentifier data type). In C#  you can generate GUID  using method `Guid.NewGuid()`

> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.

Here you find [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) and [T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)

Comment: So when the user is created the EF generates this id or it generated by sql server automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

in EF core and poco:

```
...
.Property(p => p.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is more a feature of SQL-Server, than of EF directly. EF creates the table with a unique-id field with identity on.
If you want to do that yourself, you need a unique-id field. Your object should then have a `GUID`property `Id`, which you assign `Guid.NewGuid()`for instance.

Hope that helps