# SqlException: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: asp.net, guid

Having issues storing a GUID as an uniqueidentifier in SQL SERVER.

On a Post request, I init a document:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Create([FromBody] Document Document)
{ 
    _DocumentRepository.Add(new Document {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ImanageId = "11111", Name = "Memo", Whiteout = "", Worksheet = "Firm", PacketId = "1" });
}
```

Then in my DocumentRepository:

```
public void Add(Document Document)
{
    _context.Add(Document);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

At the save changes line, I get:

> SqlException: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

In my Document class, I have have Id set as GUID.

```
public class Document
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ImanageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Worksheet { get; set; }
    public string Whiteout { get; set; }
    public string PacketId { get; set; }
    // public virtual Packet Packet { get; set; }
}
```

So, why is it converting from string?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the real code because your class property is `ImanageId` but you use `ManageId`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Entity Framework generate a GUID for a primary key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264313/how-does-entity-framework-generate-a-guid-for-a-primary-key-value)

Comment: @kblok: why is that a duplicate?

Comment: @OP: now you have fixed your typo, so that means you have written the code here by hand instead of copy-pasting it. Why?

Comment: There many post talking about using uniqueidentifier with entity framework

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just didn't want people to know I was using Imanage.

Comment: We do this type of thing all day long in our system so it's not a systemic problem, it's specific to your application. Have you checked the type of all the columns in your database table to ensure they match the types in the `Document` class? Have you used SQL Profiler to look at the request your program is sending to SQL Server?

Comment: @CraigW. It definitely is.  I believe due the setup, I made some changes in my entity and the migration file is not being updated.  I haven't used SQL Profiler, but I'll look into it.  Thanks for your input