# Disable name convention for navigation property ef-core2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I trying to use a identity class inside of my domain object but when i want to create migration for create database the ef core 2.2 say me:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Warehouse' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Existence' because it is configured as a navigation.

my dbcontext is

```
public class WarehousesContext : BaseContext<WarehousesContext>
{
    public WarehousesContext(DbContextOptions<WarehousesContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public WarehousesContext() : base() { }
    public DbSet<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Existence> Existences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exit> Exits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transfer> Transfers { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Inventory");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Warehouse>().ToTable("Warehouses");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Warehouse>().HasKey(w => w.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Warehouse>().Property(w => w.Id).HasConversion(v => v.Id, v => new WarehouseId(v));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Existence>().ToTable("Existences");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Existence>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Existence>().Property(e => e.Id).HasConversion(v => v.Id, v => new ExistenceId(v));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Existence>().OwnsOne(e => e.Warehouse);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Existence>().OwnsOne(e => e.Product);
    }

}
```

my existences class is

```
    public class Existence
{
    public ExistenceId Id { get; private set; }
    public WarehouseId Warehouse { get; private set; }
    public ProductId Product { get; private set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; private set; }
    public string Batch { get; private set; }
    private Existence() { }
    public Existence(WarehouseId warehouse, ProductId product, decimal quantity, string batch)
    {
        Warehouse = warehouse;
        Product = product;
        Quantity = quantity;
        Batch = batch;
    }

    internal void Add(decimal quantity)
    {
        Quantity += quantity;
    }

    internal void Subtract(decimal quantity)
    {
        Quantity -= quantity;
        if (Quantity < 0)
            throw new Exception();
    }
```

and my warehouseId class

```
public class WarehouseId 
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public WarehouseId()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public WarehouseId(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

i think the problem are that i use the "entityId" pattern to name my identity class so i want to know if existe some way to tell ef core "don't try to use navigation property convection here"

Answer (score 0):

Change your Existence class as below(you can add your methods accordingly)

```
public class Existence
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("Warehouse")]   
    public string WarehouseId { get; private set; }
    public ProductId Product { get; private set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; private set; }
    public string Batch { get; private set; }

    public virtual Warehouse Warehouse{get;set;)
}

public class Warehouse
{
    //your other Warehouse properties

    //add below line, if one to one relation
    public virtual Existence Existence{get; set;}
    //or, add below line, if one to many relation
    //public virtual IList<Existence> Existence{get; set;}
}
```

Remove below lines from OnModelCreating method,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Existence>().OwnsOne(e => e.Warehouse);
modelBuilder.Entity<Existence>().OwnsOne(e => e.Product);
```

and you can refer below SO question to correct your identity generation.

[How does Entity Framework generate a GUID for a primary key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264313/how-does-entity-framework-generate-a-guid-for-a-primary-key-value/41264394)

Comment: thanks for you anwser but i don't want to get a foreing key, i'm interesting in save the WarehouseId and ProductId as own type due in some scenarios i will have a separate context that only share the id class so ef will be waiting find the relation.